# Elementary Congruence problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

The problem is : 
$$19x\equiv1 \pmod {140}$$
The gcd is 1. Hence one unique solution exists. 
but, $$152x\equiv8 \pmod {140}$$
Dividing by 4,we get 
$$12x\equiv 8 \pmod {35}$$
Eventually we get from this 
$$x\equiv 24 \pmod {35}$$
My question is this (these) solution also an incongruent solution to the original congruence. 
also in the 2nd congruence $(152,140)=4$ , so 4 incongruent solutions??

Comment: How did you obtain $12x\equiv 8 \pmod {35}$ from $152x\equiv8 \pmod {140}$?

Comment: You can derive from $152x\equiv8 \pmod {140}\implies 12x\equiv8 \pmod {140}\implies 3x\equiv2 \pmod {35}$

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\gcd(19,140)=1$$ we can directly calculate the inverse of $19 \pmod{140}$ by [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

As an alternative by [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) note that the equation

$$19x\equiv1 \pmod {140}$$

is equivalent to the system

$$\begin{cases}
19x\equiv1 \pmod {7} \implies 5x\equiv1 \pmod {7}\implies x\equiv3 \pmod {7}\\\\
19x\equiv1 \pmod {5}\implies4x\equiv1 \pmod {5}\implies x\equiv-1 \pmod {5}\\\\
19x\equiv1 \pmod {4}\implies 3x\equiv1 \pmod {4}\implies x\equiv-1 \pmod {4}\end{cases}$$

thus

$$\begin{cases}x\equiv3 \pmod {7}\\\\
x\equiv-1 \pmod {20} \implies x=-1+20k
\end{cases}$$

then

$$x\equiv3 \pmod {7} \implies-1-k\equiv 3 \pmod 7\implies k\equiv 3 \pmod 7$$

therefore

$$x=59$$